# How to change the Master Page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I want to assign one master page dynamically for a pure aspx file, Anybody can tell me, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Left the ContentPlaceholder to add on it.. Actually , I tried to assign master page without using ContentPlaceHolder.. Now, I realised that, atleast one ContentPlaceholder should be there temporarily, even though we will change the master page dynamically...

Answer (score 6):

You can override OnPreInit in your default.aspx.cs and set the master page based on some value in your querystring. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        if (Request.QueryString["Master"] == "Simple")
            MasterPageFile = "~/Masterpages/Simple.Master";
    }
```

**EDIT:** the cause of your error message might be covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835877/master-page-weirdness-content-controls-have-to-be-top-level-controls-in-a-cont).

Comment: "Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page. "
Ya... I already used that.. But, I got that above error msg.. Can't open it

Comment: I tried it already, But the following error msg occurs while occurs:

Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.

System.Web.HttpException: Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.