# Load Content page without Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, webforms

I was wondering if there is a way to load Content Page without loading the Master page (ASP WebForms for .NET 4.0)

Iam working on web app where client wants to add a user to DB from two diffrent places.
Place 1 is a standard webpage under some url
Place 2 is a modal dialog box which would open in another page to allow client to add user on the fly

As in "Place2" I was thinking on using iframe, that I dont know how to avoid loading additional master page.

Any suggestions ?!

Answer (score 2):

given that scenario I would extract your functionality to an .ascx (user control) and then host that once on a content page and again on a standard page.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate MasterPage that you load dynamically based on the request. See [How to change the Master Page dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542629/how-to-change-the-master-page-dynamically)

Comment: Oh, thats great too! I will take both under considiration. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a blank master page.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:
1) extract the controls you wish to reuse to a user control
2) make the masterpage controls hide-able