# Show image from Sql Server in a asp image control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image, byte

Here is how my code is:

page.aspx:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
byte[] IMG = class.readImg(id);
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/page.aspx?ID=" + id.ToString();
Context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
Context.Response.BinaryWrite(IMG);
```

Whith this code, the only thing that shows in page.aspx is the image read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution from a similar, recent question:

[Display image from database in ASP.net with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987433/display-image-from-database-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp)

You need to use a HttpHandler class to retrieve and write the stream.

Answer (score 2):

NO need to use a HttpHandler

just use the following code 
retrieve data from SQL Server into DataTable.

Into .ASPX page

```
<img runat=server id="logoImg" alt="" src="" />
```

Into C# Code

```
byte[] imgArray =  (byte[])dTable.Rows[0][8];
logoImg.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imgArray);
```