# Image is saved to the database as binary data, now I need to extract the data and put it in an <img> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image

I please need help to get my image to display correctly in the  tag that is created in a literal control.

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string productName = dr["PRO_Name"].ToString();
            string productPrice = dr["PRO_Price"].ToString();
            byte[] productImg = (byte[])dr["PRO_Img"];

            string sProduct = @"<div class='four-shop columns isotope-item'>
                                 <div class='shop-item'>
                                  <figure>
                                  //I need the image from the data base here:
                                  <img src='" + productImg + "' alt='' />
                                  <figcaption center code herelass='item-description'>
                                  <h5>" + productName + "</h5>
                                  <span>R" + productPrice + "</span>
                                  <a href='#' class='button color'>Add to    Cart</a</figcaption>
                                  </figure>
                                  </div>
                                  </div>";
           //Im using a literal control to create the DIV dynamically for each product in the database.
           productPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sProduct));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a generic handler `(.ashx)` that get productName and use `Context.WriteBinary()` method in `ashx` file. You should pass `productName` to `ashx` as a query string:

```
<img alt="Product image" src="~/somewhere/ImageHandler.ashx?productName=" + productName + "/>"
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me. I obviously had to do a bit of extra coding but I got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the URL of your image in the `img`'s `src` attribute and not a `byte` array as you do now:

```
//Wrong:
byte[] productImg = (byte[])dr["PRO_Img"];
<img src='" + productImg + "' alt='' />
```

In order to achieve it, take a look at this answer about how to create an ASP.NET ASHX Handler and eventually retrieve the image using a URL:

[Display image from database in ASP.net with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987459/952310)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser needs and image size (I don't recommend it for large files), you may embed it as a base64 string. Look at: [Embedding base64 images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

View:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImg", "Home", new {id= Model.id})" alt="" width="150" height="200"/>
```

Controller:

```
    public FileContentResult GetImg(int id)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new Model().GetImgByID(id);

        if (byteArray != null)
        {
            return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/png");
        }
        else
        {
            //something failed, image not found!
            return null;
        }
    }
```