# How to show image with list view

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, listview

I have the following code:

```
 Dim data As Byte() = CType(oSDR("SIGNIMAGE"), Byte())
                    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
                    Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                    Image1.Visible = Convert.ToInt32(Image.FromStream(ms))
                    ms.Dispose()
                    ms.Close()
```

this is code with `<asp:image>`. I want to show image with listview or literal from the databse.

I hope masters can help me..provide example about my question

thanks
regards
arif

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987433/display-image-from-database-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp

Comment: i'm control using vb.net..