# receive error during executing with master-page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page and test page.in test page i use master page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="ServiceLayer.Recognition.test" %>
```

But during executing  i received this error:

```
Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.
```

Comment: Add html of your both master page and content page only then some one can help you.

Comment: There are various reasons for this may be white space or you forgot to add a content control on master page. Please show us your html then we can help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Master Page Weirdness - "Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835877/master-page-weirdness-content-controls-have-to-be-top-level-controls-in-a-con)